# Create custom puppet fact as target of link?

Tags: puppet

Looking for how to get the target of a symlink as a custom puppet fact via facter. How would I complete this:

```
Facter.add(:link_target) do
  setcode do
    ...
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not obvious why you would want to do this, but assuming you already know the source file and it is constant then all you would need is:

```
Facter.add(:foo_link_target) do
  setcode 'readlink /path/to/foo'
end
```

If that doesn't help, you are best to fix the question so we know what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Great, so you should mark the question as "resolved" by clicking on green tick.